# Mostrar nombre de relacion Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Como puedo mostrar el nombre del cliente con el que se relaciona?

**Migracion projects**

```
Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('nombre', 60);
            $table->string('descripcion');
            //para relacionar con cliente
            $table->integer('client_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('client_id')
                ->references('id')->on('clients')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
```

**Migracion clients**

```
Schema::create('clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('nombre', 60);
```

**Projects controller**

```
use App\Project;
use App\Client;
public function index()
    {
        $projects = Project::all();
        return view('admin/projects.index',compact('projects'));
    }
```

**Model project**

```
class Project extends Model
{
public function clients(){
        //Este proyecto pertenece a un cliente
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Client');
    }
}
```

**Model Client**

```
class Client extends Model
{
public function projects(){
        //Este cliente tiene muchos proyectos
        return $this->hasMany('App\Project');
    }
}
```

***Como puedo mostrar el nombre del cliente con el que se relaciona en la vista?***
Me sale
Trying to get property of non-object

```
@foreach($projects as $project) 
    <tbody> 
        <tr> 
            <th scope="row">{{$project->id}}</th> 
            <td>{{$project->nombre}}</td> 
            //AQUI//AQUI//AQUI//AQUI
            <td>{{$project->clients->nombre}}</td> //AQUI
            <td>{{$project->descripcion}}</td> 
            <td class="form-inline">
                <a href="{{ route('admin.projects.edit', $project->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary">Editar</a>
                {!!Form::open(['route'=>['admin.projects.destroy', $project->id], 'method' => 'DELETE'])!!}
                {!!Form::submit('Eliminar',['class'=>'btn btn-danger'])!!}
                {!!Form::close()!!}  
            </td> 
        </tr> 

    </tbody> 
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 2):

Para mantener coherencia con la forma como funciona Laravel y el método belongsTo, sugiero que utilices el singular cuando declaras la relación en `Project` y/o que agregues la llave foránea como segundo parámetro:

```
class Project extends Model
{
    public function client(){
        //Este proyecto pertenece a un cliente
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Client');
    }
}
```

Aquí tienes la referencia de Laravel (5.2) :

```
/**
 * Define an inverse one-to-one or many relationship.
 *
 * @param  string  $related
 * @param  string  $foreignKey
 * @param  string  $otherKey
 * @param  string  $relation
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function belongsTo($related, $foreignKey = null, $otherKey = null, $relation = null)
{
    // If no relation name was given, we will use this debug backtrace to extract
    // the calling method's name and use that as the relationship name as most
    // of the time this will be what we desire to use for the relationships.
    if (is_null($relation)) {
        list($current, $caller) = debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS, 2);

        $relation = $caller['function'];
    }

    // If no foreign key was supplied, we can use a backtrace to guess the proper
    // foreign key name by using the name of the relationship function, which
    // when combined with an "_id" should conventionally match the columns.
    if (is_null($foreignKey)) {
        $foreignKey = Str::snake($relation).'_id';
    }

    $instance = new $related;

    // Once we have the foreign key names, we'll just create a new Eloquent query
    // for the related models and returns the relationship instance which will
    // actually be responsible for retrieving and hydrating every relations.
    $query = $instance->newQuery();

    $otherKey = $otherKey ?: $instance->getKeyName();

    return new BelongsTo($query, $this, $foreignKey, $otherKey, $relation);
}
```

Comment: Ya encontre el error
http://laraveles.com/foro/viewtopic.php?id=5309
Estaba en client_id y debe ser clients_id 
Es decir debe ser llamado igual que la tabla mas _id
//para relacionar con cliente
$table->integer('clients_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('clients_id')
                ->references('id')->on('clients')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
                ->references('id')->on('clients')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

Comment: Es lo mismo que está explicado en mi respuesta, con otras palabras.

Answer (score 1):

Ya encontre el error
http://laraveles.com/foro/viewtopic.php?id=5309
Estaba en client_id y debe ser clients_id 
Es decir debe ser llamado igual que la tabla mas _id
//para relacionar con cliente
$table->integer('clients_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('clients_id')
                ->references('id')->on('clients')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
                ->references('id')->on('clients')
                ->onDelete('cascade');